# Будет ли сайт блокировать запросы, посылаемые через каждые 20-25 секунд?

Tags: python, python-3.x, requests

Парсинг CsGoFast.com на python3

Мне нужно сделать программу, которая будет парсить [игру](https://csgofast.com/#game/double). Сейчас я занимаюсь дизайном, поэтому спрошу наперёд. Программа будет собирать статистику выпадения разных цветов и также должна получать данные о том, какая ставка была сделана на красный в каждой игре. Из-за этого придётся получать страницу каждые 20 - 25 секунд. Будет ли сайт блокировать такие частые запросы? Если да, то можно как-то их обойти?

Для парсинга использую модуль requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Блокировать не должна, кахжые 20-25 секунд это не часто

Comment: *"Будет ли сайт блокировать такие частые запросы?"* -- мы не знаем какие критерии сайт использует. Может, если сайт видит, что не браузер запросы делает, то ограничения какие-нибудь вводит (как google например).

Answer (score 1):

Все зависит от настроек вебсервера, каждые 20-25 сек это не часто. Но если будет блокировать, то попробуйте следующее:

1. Изменяйте юзер агентов, вот актуальный список https://olegon.ru/user_agents.txt
2. Пробуйте прокси
3. Используйте selenium или phantomjs для имитации браузера, так как защита сайта от парсинга может быть построена на javascript